# How to use "created:" in Github search

Tags: github

In Github advanced search I'm found: `created: the date it was created`

But how to use this? how to search from(Something like 2012-05-05) to 2012-07-05 repositories in my keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update January 2013: source "[A Whole New Code Search](https://github.com/blog/1381-a-whole-new-code-search)":

The query below would be now expressed as: "[`created:2012-05-05..2012-07-05`](https://github.com/search?q=created:2012-05-05..2012-07-05&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)".

---

(Original answer: July 2012)

The syntax is the one described in **[SolrQuerySyntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax)**

Your query would be **[this one](https://github.com/search?q=created%3a%5B2012-05-05%20TO%202012-07-05%5D&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&language=)**:

```
https://github.com/search?q=created%3A[2012-05-05+TO+2012-07-05]&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&language=
```

Don't forget to select the "Search for" selector, putting in it the "Repositories" value, to limit the search to the repositories.